# C++ Code Results in Possible Console Output Error

Tags: c++

I am running this code from textbook: An Intro To Design Patterns in C++ with QT.

```
/* Computes and prints n! for a given n.
Uses several basic elements of C++. */

#include <iostream>
int main() {

    using namespace std;
    /*
        */

    // Declarations of variables
    int factArg = 0;
    int fact(1);
    do {
        cout << "Factorial of: ";
        cin >> factArg;
        if (factArg < 0) {
            cout << "No negative values, please!" << endl;
        }
    }
    while (factArg < 0);
    int i = 2;

    while (i <= factArg) {
        fact = fact * i;
        i = i + 1;
    }
    cout << "The Factorial of " << factArg << " is: " << fact << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output console only prints one line that says "Factorial is: "
Is that what it's suppose to do?

[image]

Comment: It works on my side. Are you sure the console allows to perform input?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is what the program should output at first; it's waiting for you to type a number. If you would step into your code you would soon find out that it will wait for an input on the following line " cin >> factArg;".

So... Go ahead, type a number and press enter :).

Answer (score -1):

Yes you code includes `cin >> factArg`which you will input in the terminal first before the program will run. You may want to put the `using namespace std` before the main function rather then in it.

Comment: Thanx a trillion. Very simple solution.